# Is there a web-based iCloud interface for editing items?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have an iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.  I'd like to use iCloud, but my Macbook Air only has OS X 10.5.8, which is too old for iCloud.  Is there a web-based interface for iCloud that I could use to edit iCloud-synced things like contacts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your iPhone let you sign up for an iCloud account, you have full access to the web services provided by iCloud.com, which include:

- Contacts
- Calendars
- Mail
- Find My iPhone

You are only limited by your computer, but still have access to the web tools.

There may be (unsupported) ways to get some of these applications on your 10.5 Mac to sync, especially with Mail. Most of iCloud uses standard networking protocols, and therefore older programs may be able to use them. One may want to tread lightly though, since this is unsupported, and may cause issues/corruption in other parts that are supported (ie, you wouldn't want to edit your contacts in a way on 10.5 even if you could, since it could break them on your iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

Other than Apple developed tools, such as at iCloud.com, there are none.

Apple has not yet release an iCloud API and keys for web development.  Currently they  only supply the necessary information and SDK for OS X and iOS developers to access iCloud.  This restricts developers from developing iCloud apps for the web, windows, android, or any other platform.

So no, you won't find a general interface that permits editing iCloud entries via anything other than OS X and iOS - at least not yet.  Perhaps Apple will open the doors to alternative APIs later, or someone will reverse engineer the API and release the details.  Even if it is reverse engineered the keys and authorization sequence will make it difficult, if not impossible, to keep such a service online without Apple eventually revoking the keys once they determine they are being improperly used.

Answer (score 0):

#### https://www.icloud.com/

You can edit your contacts and calendar events here. You can also check your mail and take a look at iWork documents.

> To access your **mail**, **contacts**, **calendars**, **Find My iPhone**, and **iWork documents** from your computer's web browser, one of these browsers is required:
>
> - Safari 5 or later
> - Firefox 5 or later
> - Internet Explorer 8 or later
> - Chrome 12 or later
>
> ([source](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4759))